# Why are @OneToMany relationships are duplicated?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

I have a 'save()' method inside a Session EJB (UpdateService) which persists an JPA Entity Bean. 
The method first removes all existing @OneToMany relations to the Entity Bean. Than the method creates new relations and persists them. This all works so far as expected.

But now I have a situation, where another Session EJB (SuperService) which is calling my first Session Bean (UpdateService) needs to update a specific JPA Entity Bean twice. So during one transaction the method UpdateService.save() is called twice for the same entity.

I can see, that in this case the second call of UpdateService.save() did not recognize that the first call has created new relationship (which - as a result, will not be removed) and so it creates an additional relationship. As a result the relationship is doubled. The magic thing is, that other data which is part of attributes of my entity bean are already updated in the second call. It seems that only the pending new relationships are not removeable.

I played already with setting the TransactionIsolation to TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED, but with no effect.
So my question is: how can I see that my entity has uncommited new relationships so that I can remove them?

I am running EclipseLink 2.5 on WildFly with MySQL.

This is a simplified part of my EJB code:

```
....
manager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
...
activeEntity = manager.find(Entity.class, sID);
// remove current TextItem List
for (TextItem aItem : activeEntity.getTextItems())
    manager.remove(aItem);
activeEntity.getTextItems().clear();
..
//  update the relationships
for (Object asingleValue : valueList) {
    TextItem newItem = new TextItem(index.getName(),
                asingleValue.toString());
    manager.persist(newItem);
    activeEntity.getTextItems().add(newItem);
}
manager.flush();
manager.detach(activeEntity);
return statusResult;
```

Comment: More description is necessary  Why does the second call not have the updated TextItems list, or does it?  Are these calls in separate transactions or maybe a different persistence context/entityManager associated to the same transaction?

Comment: Yes this is the question: why does the second call not have the new persisted relationships - or more exactly - is unable to cancel there creation? Both calls are in the same transaction. I assume that both ejb-calls are using the same entityManger. The second call reads the updated general attributes from the first call. But the result is that all new realationships are committed (form the first and second call) - even if the second call discards all relationships. (see code example)

Comment: show your entity and mappings, what is in the valueList and what is returned from activeEntity.getTextItems() before the clear.  Does calling manager.refresh(activeEntity) after the find help?